# Azure Traffic Manager and Load Balancer

Tags: load-balancing, azure, traffic-management

I have the following configuration being hosted in Azure virtual servers.

Web Server 1 and 2 located in Data Center A and Web Server 3 located in Data Center B. Each server is hosting the same sites, but duplicated from the other servers.

When traffic comes in from the internet I want it to balance the traffic across all web servers. If Web Server 1 goes down or has issues with one web site I want it to shift all sites to Web Server 2 and or 3. If there is an issue with one site on Web Server 2 I want it to shift the load to Web Server 3 fully for all sites.

Comment: I guess this can be done with Azure Traffic manager: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Batistuta, In Azure we can use Traffic Manager to distribute traffic to the available web site.
[image]
And traffic manager supports **Priority traffic-routing method**, Often an organization wants to provide reliability for its services by deploying one or more backup services in case their primary service goes down. The 'Priority' traffic-routing method allows Azure customers to easily implement this failover pattern.
[image]
More information about traffic manager, refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.